Are bilinear forms determined by their zeroes?
Suppose I have two square matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$. Suppose further that for every pair $(v,w^T)$ consisting of a row vector $v$ and column vector $w^T$, $v\mathbf{A}w^T = 0$ iff $v\mathbf{B}w^T = 0$. Does this imply that the matrices are scalar multiples of each other?
(I suppose you might phrase this more abstractly as: Is every bilinear form on a vector space determined up to scalar multiplication by its "zero locus" or set of orthogonal pairs of vectors?)
Furthermore, does the answer depend on the characteristic of the underlying field?

This is true over any field. The given condition implies that for any $w$, the annihilators $(\operatorname{span}{Aw^T})^0={v:vAw^T=0}$ and $(\operatorname{span}{Bw^T})^0={v:vBw^T=0}$ are identical to each other. Therefore the double annihilators $(\operatorname{span}{Aw^T})^{00}=\operatorname{span}{Aw^T}$ and $(\operatorname{span}{Bw^T})^{00}=\operatorname{span}{Bw^T}$ are also identical, meaning that $Aw^T$ and $Bw^T$ are always parallel to each other. The rest is straightforward.

Long story short, it's true in all fields.
$\newcommand{adj}{\operatorname{adj}}$Given a matrix $X$, call $\adj_X(v)=v^TX$. Namely, $\adj_X$ is a map $\Bbb K^n\to (\Bbb K^n)^*$. Since two functionals $f_1,f_2$ have the same $\ker$ if and only if there is a non-zero scalar $\alpha$ such that $f_1=\alpha f_2$, your condition is equivalent to saying that for all $v$ there is some $\lambda\ne 0$ such that $\lambda \adj_{A_1}(v)=\adj_{A_2}(v)$. Now, in general, for any two linear maps $T_1,T_2:V\to W$ the condtion $[\forall v,\exists \lambda \ne 0, T_1v=\lambda T_2v]$ can only happen if there is some $\mu\ne0$ such that $T_1=\mu T_2$. In fact, since $\ker T_1=\ker T_2$ and $\operatorname{im}T_2=\operatorname{im}T_1$, by the first isomorphism theorem there is some $L\in\operatorname{GL}(\operatorname{im}T_2)$ such that $T_1=LT_2$. Now, every $T_2v\ne 0$ is an eigenvector of $L$, and I leave it to you to prove that the $\lambda id$-s are the only linear maps which have all non-zero vectors as eigenvectors. Since there is some $\mu$ such that $\mu id_{\operatorname{im}T_2}\circ T_2=T_1$, a fortiori $\mu T_2=\mu id_{W}\circ T_2=T_1$.
Going back to the original problem, there indeed is some $\mu \ne 0$ such that $\mu\adj_{A_1}=\adj_{A_2}$. In particular, for all $v$ we have $v^T(A_2-\mu A_1)=0$. I.e., $\ker((A_2-\mu A_1)^T)=\Bbb K^n$, i.e. $A_2-\mu A_1=0$.
