Proving $\ker(\phi_{A}) = \ker(\phi_{B})\iff (A,B)$ is linearly dependant with, $\phi_{A}$ the Trace function associated to $A$

$\forall A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R}),$ define $\phi_{A}:M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ where >$\forall M \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R}):\phi_{A}(M) = \mathrm{Tr}(AM)$.
Prove that $\forall A,B \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})-\{ 0 \}: \ker(\phi_{A}) = \ker(\phi_{B}) \iff (A,B)$ is linearly depedant.

Since $\ker(\phi_{A})$ is a hyperplane, let $H_{A} = \ker(\phi_{A})$, the implication from right to left is not so hard to prove, however the implication from left to right is quite troublesome. My take on this is as follows.
Let $M=[m_{ij}] \in H_{A} \cap H_{B}$, $A = [a_{ij}]$ and $B = [b_{ij}]$.
We have $M \in H_{A} \implies \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{kj}m_{jk} = 0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} b_{kj}m_{jk} = 0$
As such $\forall \lambda \in\mathbb{R}: \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_{kj }-\lambda b_{kj})m_{jk} = 0$
Since $A^\intercal \in H_{A}$ then $A^{\intercal} \in H_{B}$, so $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_{kj}a_{kj} = 0$
These are the only results I could conclude.

Isn't this the same thing as the question asked 2 hours ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4972820/are-bilinear-forms-determined-by-their-zeroes ?  You can impose the constraint $\text{rank}(M) \leq 1$ if you like

For any $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$, define $\langle A,B \rangle = \textrm{Tr}(A^{T} B)$. It is well known that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is a scalar product.
Let $H$ be a hyperplan of $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$, then there exists a unique subspace $L$ such that $H^\perp = L$ and $\textrm{dim } L = 1$.
Now define $\phi_A : M \mapsto \langle M,A \rangle$. Suppose $\ker \phi_A = \ker \phi_B$, then there exists a unique subspace $L$ such that $(\ker \phi_A)^\perp = (\ker \phi_B)^\perp = L$. Now $A$ and $B$ belong to $L$, so there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A = \lambda B$.
